# Does it make sense to have a separate microservice for thread pool in Java?

Tags: java, microservices, threadpool

I am wondering if you can help me with this question, does it make sense to have a separate microservice that is responsible for managing threads, thread pool for a specific application? The threads that this microservice manage have to be executed in the other application code..

So this means that the Thread pool microservice lives in a different JVM, apart from the application code that lives in another JVM?

Which means more that threads are being created by JVM 1 and executed in JVM 2 for a different application..

Thank you.

Comment: A thread cannot be created by one JVM and then executed by a different JVM. A thread is an inherently local concept and not something distributed. So I'm inclined to say "no it does not make sense". What is your use case and why do you want a remote process create threads for your local process?

Comment: Thank you for the answer
we have a monolithic application that cannot be separated currently to different microservices,  and in this application we have many classes that each have like its own threads management/pooling, so I was wondering if we can group them into one pool, managed outside of the application resources.

Comment: When planning on how to split a big application into smaller microservices, you usually try to identify _bounded contexts_ for different business domains and then extract services one by one. "Threads" are not a business concern, but an implementation detail. You wouldn't extract "polymorphism" to a separate server either

Comment: Well said, it should not be concerned about business, then I only have the option to break up the application itself to different microservices in order to scale. The problem is when dealing with existing monolithic application is different than building new things the right way from the beginning. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First impression:** Bad idea.

---

Not a hard and fast rule, but the individual micro-services should be decoupled.

Thread management is the job of the Operating System. So, in effect, this *Thread Manager* micro-service will become unofficial OS of your architecture. As a result this architecture will become a layered one instead, with thread manager being the bottom layer.

Your micro-services should be working in the problem domain, meaning that they should be taking a unit of input (for ex: a shopping list) and returning a unit of output (for ex: purchased items off the shopping list). By making a micro-service return threads, you have broken the abstraction.

Comment: Totally make sense, almost forgot about this concept, it is that the amount of threads used in our application are many that I wanted to extract them blindly without thinking of the abstraction side of the story, appreciating your answer.

Comment: You can still centralize thread management in your application, by creating a class/dependency which handles thread management of your application. This can be done without moving it to a remote microservice. (Java already offers many classes in this direction, such as implementations of `ExecutorService`)

Comment: good point, my next question would be, is it a one thread pool per class/group of classes? or 1 thread pool for everything with bigger size?

Comment: That depends on your requirements and architecture. There is no single answer which covers all cases

Comment: @user1201957: The correct answer to that will require measurement. You can start with one base implementation and run tests around that implementation to see how it fares and if there are any hotspots or major bottlenecks. And then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @knittl and dispayName for the very helpful answers I agree, it depends on the feature, amount of usage, whether it will block other areas of the application or not.
One last question please, is there a ready API that helps managing the threads in a pool, I know about the ExecutorService, however my question, how would I know that code 1 in the application has already been served sufficiently, now switch the execution to code 2 in the application? simply, how to distribute execution for several code areas, is there a ready API ? Thanks

Comment: In reality isn't this what exactly RMI is about? Just wrap the M in RMI to a thread and do whatever processing? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni: This isn’t what RMI is about. In RMI only parameters are provided. The code execution happens entirely in the another thread in the other JVM. Here you are talking about providing the thread to another JVM. That really makes no sense at all. This is akin to me giving you my computer so that you can connect it to a power source and send an email on my behalf.

Comment: @user1201957: If execution of code 2 has to happen after the "sufficient serving" of code 1, then simply chain the execution such that code 2 is called by code 1 itself, rather than an external orchestrator which is keeping track of code 1's execution.